# Customize the xmpp openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have a requirement of building an chat app using XMPP protocol.I already installed the open-fire and configured MySQL database, i am successfully able to send and receive messages over XMPP. But as per the requirement i want to customized the XMPP and their database, so can anybody guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [openfire plugin development](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) if you want to extend the functionality of the openfire server. In case if you want to change the openfire server itself, start putting hands in to the source code and read the API spefication docs (perhaps around the defaultauthprovider, hybridauthprovider for databases stuff, not really sure if this can help you).

Comment: can i go for websocket, instead of editing the source code of xmpp openfire?

Comment: I haven't really worked much with the openfire. Can you please elaborate what do you want to do with websockets? you mean writing websockets at the openfire side and when clients talk through websockets you want to trigger off something in the openfire and let the response come back through the same websockets? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: no no no, i just wanna ask that can i go for websocket, i mean writing server side program for IM in websocket only not with xmpp or any other protocol.

Comment: You can ofcouse write it, but i guess it will be quite a bit heavy work(it depends on your requirements). Instead you can use XMPP openfire and spark (as chat client). They are apache license, just get the source code and customize according to your needs.